# Shrub ID - Texas

Tags: identification

Moved into a new house and I’m trying to ID two shrubs. I’m in North Texas, both plants kept their leaves and stayed green through winter and both are about 4’x4’. Any help is appreciated, hopefully these photos are sufficient. Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Top one is ligustrom  , small flowers but nice smell, bees love it. They will grow into a small tree if not pruned.  The lower one looks like euonymus; Not certain because there are a few kinds and often they are varigated with white.

Comment: Yep, further investigation confirms Ligustrom (privet). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The second photo  is a *Euonymus*, probably *E. japonicus* http://architecturalplants.com/plants/id/euonymus-japonicus.

The first I'm not sure - I can't see the structure of the flowers properly from the photograph, but it may also be another variety of *Euonymus*. Another, clearer photo of the flowers might be helpful. Are the flowers fragrant?

Comment: Excellent. Searching for more photos by name, I believe you are correct. E. Japonicus. Thank you!